# Prevent XSS attacks when echoing HTML using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, xss

I have a simple bimple function which echoes this:

```
echo '<button name="wooba" onclick="alert(this.name)">Say name</button>'
```

This just works fine, but If a user edits the HTML using a Chrome or Firefox, he can modify the code to output something like:

```
echo '<button name="wooba" onclick="alert('XSS :D')">Say name</button>'
```

I have set the **only http** on the php ini relating the cookies, but is there any way to prevent the user from modifying and successfully changing the site's javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: A user manually editing code which has already been output to the browser is not XSS. There's nothing you can do about it, but equally it should not do any harm (XSS-wise) because they're only messing with their own copy of the page, it doesn't affect anything on the server. Are you really asking about the user just editing the code with the developer tools, or about a different scenario?

Comment: Exactly that, the user editing the code from my page with his developer tools. @ADyson I think I have misunderstood basic XSS principles.

Comment: Yes. XSS occurs when some input from one user manages to affect the behaviour of the page for a different user and/or affect a different application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the document reaches a user's browser it is theirs to manipulate how they like. This in itself isn't XSS. An XSS exploit exists when a bad actor can inject a script in other people's document. In your example, so long as `this.name` doesn't come from user input you don't have a problem.

Comment: Thanks! @Andrew Gillis that was it.

Comment: No problem. It's better to ask yourself these questions than to assume it's safe. Keep a special eye out for the [OWASP Top 10](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/).